# Inno Setup: RegValueExists does not return true, trying to check Registry Key

Tags: inno-setup

I want to show Components based on the existence of a registry key:

```
[Components]
Name: "MyProgram"; Description: "MyProgram"; Check: RegistryCheck
```

This is the corresponding function:

```pascal
function RegistryCheck: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Bricsys', 'RegisteredOwner')    
  end;
```

I don't know what's the mistake, the installed program which has to be checked is x64, running IS on a x64 machine.

*Key:*

Rootkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Name:    RegisteredOwner
Type:    REG_SZ
Data:    User

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to install on a 64bit OS you may be looking in  the wrong `RootKey`.

Try using the following instead...

```pascal
RegValueExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Bricsys', 'RegisteredOwner')
```